# What is the earliest callback one can hook in the Rails Framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have found the before_dispatch and after_dispatch in dispatcher.rb but I need to access something earlier. Like around when Rails.public_path is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you can take a look at `config/boot.rb` (don't change it please).  In there, you'll find it will load the file `config/preinitializer.rb` if it exists.  That might be overkill though, you probably can do what you want by creating an initializer in `config/initializers/`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's needed for Mongrel or Apache, are You sure it can not be done by configuration?